# WPF Using multiple filters on the same ListCollectionView

Tags: wpf, filter, listcollectionview

I'm using the MVVM design pattern, with a ListView bound to a ListCollectionView on the ViewModel.  I also have several comboboxes that are used to filter the ListView.  When the user selects an item from the combobox, the ListView is filtered for the selected item.  Whenever I want to filter on top of what is already filtered, it undoes my previous filter like it never happened.  The same is also true for removing a filter.  Removing a filter for one combobox removes all filters and displays the original list.  Is it possible to have multiple, separate filters on the same ListCollectionView?

Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply not supported?  You can find a screen capture of my application [here](http://7usvig.blu.livefilestore.com/y1pUetcsxXc3zuj5oVMbQedmr30XmK8PhIF24Azw7if-Zd5JHPV_HbV_Yybs5pm_3Jfpwrn90inBOsX1YjOCbUjLHFzvVQxaq_M/Capture.PNG) to see what I am trying to accomplish.  Here's my code for filtering...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Filter the list
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filter">Criteria and Item to filter the list</param>
    [MediatorMessageSink("FilterList", ParameterType = typeof(FilterItem))]
    public void FilterList(FilterItem filter)
    {
        // Make sure the list can be filtered...
        if (Products.CanFilter)
        {
            // Now filter the list
            Products.Filter = delegate(object obj)
            {
                Product product = obj as Product;

                // Make sure there is an object
                if (product != null)
                {
                    bool isFiltered = false;
                    switch (filter.FilterItemName)
                    {
                        case "Category":
                            isFiltered = (product.Category.IndexOf(filter.Criteria, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) != -1 ? true : false;
                            break;

                        case "ClothingType":
                            isFiltered = (product.ClothingType.IndexOf(filter.Criteria, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) != -1 ? true : false;
                            break;

                        case "ProductName":
                            isFiltered = (product.ProductName.IndexOf(filter.Criteria, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) != -1 ? true : false;
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    return isFiltered;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 29):

Every time you set Filter property you reset previous filter. This is a fact. Now how can you have multiple filters?

As you know, there are two ways to do filtering: `CollectionView` and `CollectionViewSource`. In the first case with `CollectionView` we filter with delegate, and to do multiple filters I'd create a class to aggregate custom filters and then call them one by one for each filter item. Like in the following code:

```
  public class GroupFilter
  {
    private List<Predicate<object>> _filters;

    public Predicate<object> Filter {get; private set;}

    public GroupFilter()
    {
      _filters = new List<Predicate<object>>();
      Filter = InternalFilter;
    }

    private bool InternalFilter(object o)
    {
      foreach(var filter in _filters)
      {
        if (!filter(o))
        {
          return false;
        }
      }

      return true;
    }

    public void AddFilter(Predicate<object> filter)
    {
      _filters.Add(filter);
    }

    public void RemoveFilter(Predicate<object> filter)
    {
      if (_filters.Contains(filter))
      {
        _filters.Remove(filter);
      }
    }    
  }

  // Somewhere later:
  GroupFilter gf = new GroupFilter();
  gf.AddFilter(filter1);
  listCollectionView.Filter = gf.Filter;
```

To refresh filtered view you can make a call to `ListCollectionView.Refresh()` method.

And in the second case with `CollectionViewSource` you use `Filter` event to filter collection. You can create multiple event handlers to filter by different criteria. To read more about this approach check this wonderful article by Bea Stollnitz: [How do I apply more than one filter?](https://github.com/bstollnitz/old-wpf-blog/tree/master/29-MultipleFilters) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20201007042629/https://github.com/bstollnitz/old-wpf-blog/tree/master/29-MultipleFilters))

Hope this helps.

Cheers, Anvaka.

Answer (score 8):

Every time the user filters, your code is *replacing* the `Filter` delegate in your collection view with a new, fresh one. Moreover, the new one only checks the particular criteria the user just selected with a `ComboBox`.

What you want is a single filter handler that checks all criteria. Something like:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    productsView = new ListCollectionView(products);
    productsView.Filter += FilterProduct;
}

public Item SelectedItem
{
    //get,set omitted. set needs to invalidate filter with refresh call
}

public Type SelectedType
{
    //get,set omitted. set needs to invalidate filter with refresh call
}

public Category SelectedCategory
{
    //get,set omitted. set needs to invalidate filter with refresh call
}

public ICollection<Product> FilteredProducts
{
    get { return productsView; }
}

private bool FilterProduct(object o)
{
    var product = o as Product;

    if (product == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (SelectedItem != null)
    {
        // filter according to selected item
    }

    if (SelectedType != null)
    {
        // filter according to selected type
    }

    if (SelectedCategory != null)
    {
        // filter according to selected category
    }

    return true;
}
```

Your view can now just bind to the appropriate properties and the filtering will just work.