# How to apply multiple filters on Listview

Tags: wpf

**My DataModel :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace LogViewerApplication
{

    public class LogRead
    {

        string _path;
        List<string> _strList;

        public List<string> StrList 
        {
            get { return _strList; } 
        }

        public LogRead()
        {
            _path = @"D:\Log viewer (project)\Test_log.txt";
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  To read the file and then to store the records in a List. 
        /// </summary>
        public void GetFile()
        {
            //_path = @"D:\Log viewer (project)\presentation_log.txt";
            string _pattern = @"^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}";
            _strList = new List<string>();

            using (StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(_path))
            {
                string sLine = "";
                while ((sLine = objReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    _strList.Add(sLine);
                }
            }

            int j;
            string sub;
            for (int k = 0; k < _strList.Count; k++)
            {
                if (!Regex.IsMatch(_strList[k], _pattern))
                {

                    j = k;
                    sub = _strList[k];
                    _strList[j - 1] = _strList[j - 1] + " " + sub;
                    _strList.RemoveAt(k);
                    //Console.WriteLine(strlist[k]);
                    //Console.WriteLine();
                    k--;
                }
            }
        }

    }


    public enum Severe { Normal, Debug, Critical }


    public class LogViewerModel
    {


        public DateTime Datetime { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public Severe Severity { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; } 

    }

}
```

**My ViewModel :**

```
namespace LogViewerApplication
{

    class LogViewerViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ObservableCollection<LogViewerModel> _logViewerModelCollection; 
        LogRead _logRead;
        ICollectionView _viewSource;
        //GroupFilter gf;

        public ICollectionView ViewSource
        {
            get
            {
                if(_viewSource==null)
                {
                    _viewSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_logViewerModelCollection);

                }
                return _viewSource;
            }

        }


        #region Commands

        #region SetColorCommand

        private RelayCommand _setColorCommand;

        public ICommand SetColorCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_setColorCommand == null)
                {
                    _setColorCommand = new RelayCommand(SetColor);
                }

                return _setColorCommand;

            }
        }
        private void SetColor(Object param)
        {
            if (_norm && !_dbg && !_crtcl)
            {


                _viewSource.Filter = delegate(object item)
                {
                    return ((LogViewerModel)item).Severity == Severe.Normal;
                };

            }

            else if (_dbg && !_norm && !_crtcl)
            {

                _viewSource.Filter = delegate(object item)
                {
                    return ((LogViewerModel)item).Severity == Severe.Debug;
                };
            }

            else if (_crtcl && !_norm && !_dbg)
            {

                _viewSource.Filter = delegate(object item)
                {
                    return ((LogViewerModel)item).Severity == Severe.Critical;
                };


            }

            else if (_norm && _dbg && !_crtcl)
            {

                _viewSource.Filter = delegate(object item)
                {
                    return ((LogViewerModel)item).Severity == Severe.Normal || ((LogViewerModel)item).Severity == Severe.Debug;
                };

            }

            else if (_norm && _crtcl && !_dbg)
            {


                _viewSource.Filter = delegate(object item)
                {
                    return ((LogViewerModel)item).Severity == Severe.Normal || ((LogViewerModel)item).Severity == Severe.Critical;
                };

            }
            else if (_dbg && _crtcl && !_norm)
            {

                _viewSource.Filter = delegate(object item)
                {
                    return ((LogViewerModel)item).Severity == Severe.Debug || ((LogViewerModel)item).Severity == Severe.Critical;
                };

            }

            else if (_norm && _dbg && _crtcl)
            {

                _viewSource.Filter = delegate(object item)
                {
                    return true;
                };

            }

            else
            {

                _viewSource.Filter = delegate(object item)
                {
                    return false;
                };


            }

        }

        #endregion

        #region SearchCommand

        private RelayCommand _searchCommand;
        public ICommand SearchCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_searchCommand == null)
                {
                    _searchCommand = new RelayCommand(Search);
                }

                return _searchCommand;

            }
        }
        private void Search(object param)
        {
            string str = param as string;

            if (_searchSource == "Source")
            {

                _viewSource.Filter = delegate(object item)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int index = ((LogViewerModel)item).Source.IndexOf(str, 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                        return index > -1;
                    }
                    //return ((LogViewerModel)item).Severity == Severe.Normal;

                };

            }
            else if (_searchSource == "Message")
            {

                _viewSource.Filter = delegate(object item)
                {

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int index = ((LogViewerModel)item).Message.IndexOf(str, 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                        return index > -1;
                    }
                    //return ((LogViewerModel)item).Severity == Severe.Normal;

                };

            }
            else
            {


                _viewSource.Filter = delegate(object item)
                {
                    return true;
                };


            }

        }

        #endregion

        #region DateFilterCommand

        private RelayCommand _dateFilterCommand;
        public ICommand DateFilterCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_dateFilterCommand == null)
                {
                    _dateFilterCommand = new RelayCommand(DateFilter);
                }

                return _dateFilterCommand;

            }
        }
        private void DateFilter(object param)
        {

            string _startDate;
            string _endDate;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_startHour) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(_startMinute) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(_endHour) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(_endMinute))
            {
                _startDate = _startDay + "-" + StartMonth + "-" + _startYear;
                _endDate = _endDay + "-" + _endMonth + "-" + _endYear + " " + "23" + ":" + "59" + ":" + "59";

                try
                {
                    DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(_startDate);
                    DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(_endDate);
                    _viewSource.Filter = delegate(object item)
                    {
                        return (((LogViewerModel)item).Datetime >= startDate) && (((LogViewerModel)item).Datetime <= endDate);
                    };
                }

                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a valid DATE range..!!!!");
                }

            }

            else
            {
                _startDate = _startDay + "-" + StartMonth + "-" + _startYear + " " + _startHour + ":" + _startMinute;
                _endDate = _endDay + "-" + _endMonth + "-" + _endYear + " " + _endHour + ":" + _endMinute + ":" + "59";

                try
                {
                    DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(_startDate);
                    DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(_endDate);
                    _viewSource.Filter = delegate(object item)
                    {
                        return (((LogViewerModel)item).Datetime >= startDate) && (((LogViewerModel)item).Datetime <= endDate);
                    };
                }

                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a valid DATE range..!!!!");
                }
            }

        }


        #endregion


        #endregion



        public LogViewerViewModel()
        {
            _logRead = new LogRead();
            _logRead.GetFile();

            _logViewerModelCollection= new ObservableCollection<LogViewerModel>();
            loaddata();
            //gf = new GroupFilter();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// It is used to split the string property wise and to store the data
        /// into an ObservableCollection. 
        /// </summary>
        public void loaddata()
        {
            int listSize = _logRead.StrList.Count;
            DateTime dateTime;
            string source;
            Severe severity;
            string message;

            for (int k = 0; k < listSize; k++)
            {
                int flag = 0;
                string str = _logRead.StrList[k];

                //To check if a particular log entry is valid or not
                //on the basis of "Severity". 
                foreach (string s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Severe)))
                {
                    bool check = Regex.IsMatch(str, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape(s)));
                    if (check)
                    {
                        flag = 1;
                        break;

                    }
                }

                //If log entry is Valid then execute the following Code.
                if (flag == 1)
                {
                    //dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(str.Substring(0, 18));
                    dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(str.Substring(0, 19), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    string lft = str.Substring(21, str.Length - 21);
                    int c = 4;
                    string delimStr = ":";
                    char[] delimiter = delimStr.ToCharArray();

                    string[] x = lft.Split(delimiter, c);
                    int size = x.Length;
                    if (size == 2)
                    {
                        source = x[0];
                        severity =(Severe)Enum.Parse(typeof(Severe),x[1].Trim());
                        message = " ";

                        AssignData(dateTime, source, severity, message);


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                        {
                            if (x[i].Length == 1)
                            {
                                while (i < size - 1)
                                {
                                    x[i] = x[i + 1];
                                    i++;
                                }
                                Array.Resize(ref x, i);
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                        int len = x.Length;
                        if (len == 2)
                        {
                            source = x[0];
                            severity = (Severe)Enum.Parse(typeof(Severe),x[1].Trim());
                            message = " ";

                            AssignData(dateTime, source, severity, message);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (len >= 4)
                            {

                                x[2] = x[2] + x[3];
                                Array.Resize(ref x, 3);
                            }
                            source = x[0];
                            severity = (Severe)Enum.Parse(typeof(Severe),x[1].Trim());
                            message = x[2].Trim();

                            AssignData(dateTime,source,severity,message);


                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }

        /// <summary>
        /// It is used to add the data into an ObservableCollection named as            'LogViewerModelCollection'.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dateTime">DateTime for log entry</param>
        /// <param name="source">Source File for log entry </param>
        /// <param name="severity">Severity for log entry</param>
        /// <param name="message">Description for log entry</param>
        public void AssignData(DateTime dateTime,string source,Severe severity,string message)
        {
            _logViewerModelCollection.Add(new LogViewerModel
            {
                Datetime = dateTime,
                Source = source,
                Severity = severity,
                Message = message
            });
        }

        #region Properties
        bool _norm=true;
        bool _dbg = true;
        bool _crtcl=true;
        string _searchSource;

        string _startDay;
        string _startMonth;
        string _startYear;
        string _startHour;
        string _startMinute;

        string _endDay;
        string _endMonth;
        string _endYear;
        string _endHour;
        string _endMinute;

        public bool LowChk
        {
            get { return _norm; }
            set 
            {
                _norm = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LowChk");
            }
        }
        public bool MediumChk
        {
            get { return _dbg; }
            set 
            { 
                _dbg = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MediumChk");
            }
        }
        public bool HighChk
        {
            get { return _crtcl; }
            set 
            {
                _crtcl = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("HighChk");
            }
        }
        public string SearchSource
        {
            get { return _searchSource; }
            set
            {
                _searchSource = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SearchSource");
            }


        }


        public string StartDay
        {
            get { return _startDay; }
            set { _startDay=value;}
        }

        public string StartMonth
        {
            get { return _startMonth; }
            set { _startMonth = value; }
        }
        public string StartYear
        {
            get { return _startYear; }
            set { _startYear=value;}
        }
        public string StartHour
        {
            get { return _startHour; }
            set { _startHour=value;}
        }
        public string StartMinute
        {
            get { return _startMinute; }
            set { _startMinute = value; }
        }
        public string EndDay
        {
            get { return _endDay; }
            set { _endDay = value; }
        }
        public string EndMonth
        {
            get { return _endMonth; }
            set { _endMonth = value; }
        }
        public string EndYear
        {
            get { return _endYear; }
            set { _endYear=value;}
        }
        public string EndHour
        {
            get { return _endHour; }
            set { _endHour=value;}
        }
        public string EndMinute
        {
            get { return _endMinute; }
            set { _endMinute = value; }
        }


        #endregion


        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**RelayCommand's Logic :**

```
namespace LogViewerApplication
{
    public class RelayCommand:ICommand
    {

        #region Fields

        readonly Action<object> _execute;
        readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        #endregion // Fields

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new command.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
        /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        #endregion // Constructors




        #region ICommand Members

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }


        //public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**APP.xaml CODE:-**

```
namespace LogViewerApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            //base.OnStartup(e);


            FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));



            LogViewerViewModel logViewerViewModel = new LogViewerViewModel();

            LogViewer window = new LogViewer();
            window.Show();
            window.DataContext = logViewerViewModel;
        }


    }
}
```

**XAML CODE :**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!--<ph:LogViewerViewModel x:Key="log"/>-->
    <!--<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border
         Name="Border"
         Background="LightBlue"
         BorderBrush="Black"
         BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
         CornerRadius="6,6,0,0" >
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           ContentSource="Header"
           Margin="12,2,12,2"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>-->

    <!--<Style  TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TabPanel
         Grid.Row="0"
         Panel.ZIndex="1"
         Margin="0,0,4,-1"
         IsItemsHost="True"
         Background="Transparent" />
                        <Border
         Grid.Row="1"
         BorderBrush="Black"
         BorderThickness="1"
         CornerRadius="0, 12, 12, 12" >
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush>
                                    <GradientStop Color="LightBlue" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>-->

    <Style x:Key="ItemContStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TruBrush" Color="Green"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="VinuBrush" Color="Red"/>

        </Style.Resources>

        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />

        <Style.Triggers>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Severity}" Value="Debug">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TruBrush}" />

            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Severity}" Value="Critical">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource VinuBrush}" />

            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>


<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.4*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.6*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListView x:Name="_listView" x:FieldModifier="private" Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  Margin="8,9,11,0" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemContStyle}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding ViewSource}" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="_gridView">
                    <GridViewColumn Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Datetime}" Header="Date/Time"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="220" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source}" Header="Source"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Severity}" Header="Severity"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Message}">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>

                            <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Message" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"/>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <TabControl  Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Margin="8,9,11,0">
        <TabItem Header="FilterBySeverity">
            <StackPanel>
                <Expander Header="Color Code" Margin="0,10,0,20" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Expanded="Expander_Expanded">
                    <Expander.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip>View Severity in Colors</ToolTip>
                    </Expander.ToolTip>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <RadioButton Margin="20,8,0,8">Enable</RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton Margin="20,0,0,8">Disable</RadioButton>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander>

                <CheckBox x:Name="_low" x:FieldModifier="private" Margin="8,10,0,12" IsChecked="{Binding LowChk, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">Low</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox x:Name="_medium" x:FieldModifier="private" Margin="8,0,0,12" IsChecked="{Binding MediumChk, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">Medium</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox x:Name="_high" x:FieldModifier="private" Margin="8,0,0,40" IsChecked="{Binding HighChk, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">High</CheckBox>
                <Button x:Name="_show" Width="100" Margin="8,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding Path=SetColorCommand}" >Show
                    <Button.BitmapEffect>
                        <BitmapEffectGroup>
                            <OuterGlowBitmapEffect/>
                            <DropShadowBitmapEffect/>
                            <BevelBitmapEffect/>
                        </BitmapEffectGroup>
                    </Button.BitmapEffect>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="FilterByTimeDate">
            <Grid Height="250" Width="600" Margin="0,20,350,100">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Label Grid.Row="0" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Height="80" Width="Auto">Enter the time range for your search</Label>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Width="50" Margin="0,30,5,0" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold">From:</Label>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40" Width="Auto">
                            <Label>Day:</Label>
                            <TextBox Margin="0,0,5,5" Height="20" Width="30" Text="{Binding Path=StartDay, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            <Label>Month:</Label>
                            <TextBox Margin="0,0,5,5" Height="20" Width="30" Text="{Binding Path=StartMonth, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            <Label>Year:</Label>
                            <TextBox Margin="0,0,0,5" Height="20" Width="80" Text="{Binding Path=StartYear, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30" Width="Auto">
                            <Label>Hour:</Label>
                            <TextBox Margin="0,0,5,5" Height="20" Width="30" Text="{Binding Path=StartHour, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            <Label>Minute:</Label>
                            <TextBox Margin="0,2,5,10" Height="20" Width="30" Text="{Binding Path=StartMinute, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Button Grid.Row="2" Height="30" Width="100" Command="{Binding DateFilterCommand}">Show</Button>
                    </Grid>
                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Width="30" Margin="15,30,2,0" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold">To:</Label>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="3">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40">
                        <Label>Day:</Label>
                            <TextBox Margin="0,7,10,15" Height="20" Width="30" Text="{Binding Path=EndDay, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            <Label>Month:</Label>
                            <TextBox Margin="0,7,10,15" Height="20" Width="30" Text="{Binding Path=EndMonth, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            <Label>Year:</Label>
                            <TextBox Margin="0,7,10,15" Height="20" Width="80" Text="{Binding Path=EndYear, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30">
                        <Label>Hour:</Label>
                            <TextBox Margin="0,2,10,10" Height="20" Width="30" Text="{Binding Path=EndHour, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            <Label>Minute:</Label>
                        <TextBox Margin="0,2,10,10" Height="20" Width="30" Text="{Binding Path=EndMinute, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Searching">
            <Grid Height="150" Width="300">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,12,0,0" Width="82.033" Background="AliceBlue">FindWhat:</Label>
                <Label Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,14,0,0" Width="80.097">EnterText:</Label>
                <ComboBox x:Name="FindWhat" x:FieldModifier="private" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,13" Text="{Binding Path=SearchSource, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Source"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Message"/>
                </ComboBox>
                <TextBox x:Name="EnterText" x:FieldModifier="private" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,14,0,0"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="CoolTabButton"  Margin="0,15,0,12" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=EnterText, Path=Text}">OK</Button>
                <!--Text="{Binding SearchingText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"-->
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

So guys i am facing a problem, when i select a filter after another filter then i do not get the previous filtered data in my listview..i mean 2nd filter applies on a fresh list....All the three filter are working nicely individually but when work in chaining then always all the filters works on fresh list nt the previous filtered list...
Guys please help me....
please send me a proper code of your logic to solve this problem....

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934935/wpf-using-multiple-filters-on-the-same-listcollectionview

Answer (score 0):

You may check if this could suit your needs : http://dotnetexplorer.blog.com/2011/04/07/wpf-itemscontrol-generic-staticreal-time-filter-custom-control-presentation/

This is a multi filter componenent which work on most common .net collection and attach itself to any WPF ItemsControl

The only drawback is that this is a component that stand outside your ItemsControl...