# How can I use search in the grid using CollectionView with multiple conditions?

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionview

I have Textbox and Comboboxs and a GridView and I would like to filter some columns of the grid with all controls ( Comboboxs and the Textbox ) , I have this code that return a view filtered with one condition ( Textbox ) to a custom column .

**Remark:**  I'm not using MVVM pattern.

```
    GridView.ItemsSource = MyList.ToList();
    ListCollectionView view = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyList);

    view.Filter = delegate (object item) { return (item as User).Name.Contains(Name_txt.Text); };
    GridView.ItemsSource = view;


    public class User 
     {
       public Id { get; set; }
       public Name { get; set; }
     }
```

How can I filter the datagrid columns with more than one condition ( input ) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF Using multiple filters on the same ListCollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934935/wpf-using-multiple-filters-on-the-same-listcollectionview)

Comment: No because I'm not used MVVM pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add all conditions to the `Filter` predicate, e.g.:

```
view.Filter = delegate (object item)
{ 
    User user = item as User;
    if (user == null)
        return false;

    return user.Name.Contains(Name_txt.Text)
        && comboBox1.SelectedItem == ?
        && ...; 
};
```